# Add buttons to asp:table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, button, html-table

I'm sorry for this simple question but I did not find an answer:

I created an asp:table with one row and two cells. How can I add a simple button to each cell?
It's simple with an HTML table. You should drag and drop from the toolbox. How can I do the same thing with and asp table?

Answer (score 0):

You can this from code behind:

```
foreach (TableRow row in yourTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Some Button";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        cell.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```